# For any two points $x_1$, $x_2$ in a convex set $D$, how does the following hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, convex-analysis

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two distinct points in a convex set $D\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If the origin lies on the line connecting these two points $x_1$ and $x_2$, how to show that the following equality holds.

\begin{equation}
\|x_1\|+\|x_2\|=\|x_1-x_2\|\tag{1}
\end{equation}

To do this, I take a scalar $\alpha\in{[0,1]}$ such that the line connecting $x_1$ and $x_2$ given as $L(x_1,x_2)=\alpha{x_1}+(1-\alpha)x_2$. Further, I proceed to find out an expression for $\alpha$, for which $L(x_1,x_2)=0$. But I have no idea how to prove eq. (1) from thereon. Any suggestions or comments in this regard will be very helpful.

Comment: This equality actually doesn't depend on having a convex set $D$. It holds because $x_1, 0, x_2$ are collinear.

Comment: Thanks for your mention. Yes I see that.  But in general case also, how to show that eq. (1) holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If either $x_1$ or $x_2$ is $0$ then there's nothing to prove. Otherwise $0$ must lie inside the line segment joining $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Then there exists $0<\alpha<1$ such that $0=\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2$ which implies $$x_2=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}x_1$$
Then $$\|x_1-x_2\|=\left\|x_1-\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}x_1\right\|=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\|x_1\|$$
And $$\|x_1\|+\|x_2\|=\|x_1\|+\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\|x_1\|=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\|x_1\|$$